# terraform include parts of the definition of a resource block with a remote file template

Tags: terraform, newrelic, terraform-template-file

Is it possible to include parts of a resource definition to be injected from a remote file? For e.g., I am creating a dashboard using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/latest/docs/resources/one_dashboard by defining each page contained in the dashboard using the page {} blocks.

In the below example I have three page definitions under resource {}. Is it possible to replace each or all of my page {} block definitions to source the content from a remote file?

**Expected Definition**

```
resource "newrelic_one_dashboard" "exampledash" {

  name = "New Relic Terraform Example with three pages"

  page {
      // reference to remote file with contents for page 1
  }

  page {
      // reference to remote file with contents for page 2
  }
  
  page {
      // reference to remote file with contents for page 3
  }  
}

OR

resource "newrelic_one_dashboard" "exampledash" {

  name = "New Relic Terraform Example with three pages"

   // reference to remote file with all page {} definitions

}
```

**Actual definition**

```
resource "newrelic_one_dashboard" "exampledash" {

  name = "New Relic Terraform Example with three pages"

  page {
    name = "Page1"

    widget_bar {
      title = "Average transaction duration, by application"
      row = 1
      column = 1

      nrql_query {
        account_id = var.account_id
        query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT count(1) FACET appName"
      }
        filter_current_dashboard = true
    }

    widget_line {
        title = "response time view"
        row = 2
        column = 1
        width = 4
        height = 4
        # drilldown_dashboard_id = self.id
        nrql_query {
            account_id = var.account_id
            query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT average(duration) FACET appName"
        }            
    }    

  }

  page {
    name = "Page2"

    widget_bar {
      title = "Average transaction duration, by application"
      row = 1
      column = 1

      nrql_query {
        account_id = var.account_id
        query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT count(1) FACET appName"
      }
        filter_current_dashboard = true

    }

    widget_line {
        title = "response time view"
        row = 2
        column = 1
        width = 4
        height = 4
        # drilldown_dashboard_id = self.id
        nrql_query {
            account_id = var.account_id
            query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT average(duration) FACET appName"
        }            
    }    

  }

  page {
    name = "Page3"

    widget_bar {
      title = "Average transaction duration, by application"
      row = 1
      column = 1

      nrql_query {
        account_id = var.account_id
        query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT count(1) FACET appName"
      }
        filter_current_dashboard = true

    }

    widget_line {
        title = "response time view"
        row = 2
        column = 1
        width = 4
        height = 4
        # drilldown_dashboard_id = self.id
        nrql_query {
            account_id = var.account_id
            query      = "FROM Transaction SELECT average(duration) FACET appName"
        }            
    }    

  }    
}
```

Expectation

Comment: Not in TF. Maybe with Terragrunt you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific resource that you are using but I would start with the [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html) function.

I've used it like this in the past:

```
data "template_file" "policy" {
  count    = "${var.enabled == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  template = "${file(./filename.json)}"

  vars = "${var.iam-policy-file-vars}"
}
```

Comment: I did look at File and templatefile functions. My requirement is to keep the entire resource block in the code but only include page {} blocks from a remote file. From the documentation, the file reference has to be local and has to be on the right side of a key value pair. But cannot be embedded directly if I understand them correctly